# How do I exclude a code path when running a unit test on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit

I have some code that throws an exception when run from a logic test in ocunit. I would like to ignore this code and test the rest of the functionality without having to setup an application test nor having to decompose the method.

For example:

```
-(void)testMethod {
    BOOL result = NO;
    UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]; //throws exception in ocunit
    ...
    return result;
}
```

How can I call this from a unit test with the UIFont creation excluded?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Why does that method throw an exception during testing?

Comment: I was trying to answer my own question just to document the work around I found, but it turns out I don't have the cred to do that.

Comment: Add a "**EDIT**" section to your question then.

Comment: You can answer your own question, but [not earlier that 8 hours from posting it if you have less than 100 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86186/189763).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the UIFont call in an if block and use NSClassFromString to dynamically load a SenTestCase class.

example:

```
-(void)testMethod {
    BOOL result = NO;
    if(!NSClassFromString(@"SenTestCase")) {
        UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]; //throws exception in ocunit
    }
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very much a workaround. You should just separate your logic code out and only test the logic code.  'UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];' is not logic code. In your unit test you could create your label and call method that sets the font, then test your label STAssertTrue(label.font.pointSize == 12, @"blah").

Comment: Agreed. This is very much a hack and shouldn't be used indiscriminately. With that said, I still found it useful in one specific instance and I thought others might as well.